# can't log in to centos 7 VPS /lib64 missing?

Tags: ssh, root

This never happened to me before, but I cannot log in as root. After typing in password, it says

> Last failed login:
>
> bin/bash: No such file or directory
> Connection closed.

Besides contacting my provider, I am not sure what to do.  But often they don't help, as it is not a "managed" account...by them anyway.

Today I did the command `sudo purge` on my home computer imac the terminal of which is used to connect to remote server...  I am not sure if it could be that?
I was making space for ADOBE applications having trouble running.

Other than that I can't think of anything.  But I've now deleted the /etc/ssh keys list - so probably made a mess of things.

UPDATE: the provider says `/lib64`  missing altogether in which case how could that happen and how have I logged in previously if that is the case?

Comment: Looks like your password file entry (in `/etc/passwd`) has had the leading slash `/` removed from your shell choice. Log in via another user and use `sudo`, and then fix the password entry (`sudo chsh root`), or failing that boot in single user mode and issue the command that way (single user on most UNIXs will fall back to `/bin/sh` when the shell set for root is missing).

Comment: it won't let me log in as other user either.

Comment: Then maybe bash has been deleted? I think you may have to go down the single user mode, and log in via root that way.

Comment: what is the single user mode? anyway i think i deleted accidentally libraries while untaring something. in any case the provider booted from recovery and got in replacing missing libraries so now working.

Comment: You can boot the linux kernel with the "single" or "-s" flag. Then rather than continuing into "multiuser mode", it stops and prompts for root's login password and will log you in with root's chosen a shell, or `/bin/sh` if that fails. It's kind of like recovery mode, but requires little or no major damage to the OS.